# Custom right side navigation bar button

Tags: ios, uibutton, uinavigationbar

I added a right bar button to the tableView in the storyboard, created an IB action which opens another window. Everything works fine. But now I want to use a custom Image for that button. I found this:

```
    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[button setImage:infoIconImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Which I guess with a few extra lines of code will do the job,
but I can't seem to understand what name that button has in the code. How I relate that button from the storyboard to the code.

Beginner question, sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an IBOutlet just like you linked your action from your storyboard to your .h file. Name it *button*, and you're good to go !

BTW, you can set "standard" images in your storyboard : select the button, go to the Attribute Inspector in the Utilities bar of Xcode (right bar), and change the Identifier !

*Edit :*

Have a look over there to use your own image :

[Customize UIBarButtonItem](http://mobiledevelopertips.com/user-interface/ios-5-customize-uinavigationbar-and-uibarbuttonitem-with-appearance-api.html)

The part about the UIBarButtonItem is near the end of the article.

Comment: Thanks, that answers my question, but raises another one. It created a type UIBarButtonItem. Any ideas how to customize it(use custom image)?    The above code snippet deals with UIButton instead...

Comment: See my update for custom image, in case the solution you posted doesn't work :)

Comment: The code I posted below worked out nicely, the custom button is there, but for some reason the action is not working anymore...

Answer (score 0):

OK, I found there is a property customView. SO here it is:

```
    // Set the custom back button
UIImage *infoIconImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"info-button.png"];
//create the button and assign the image
UIButton *iButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[iButton setImage:infoIconImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];

//set the frame of the button to the size of the image
iButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, infoIconImage.size.width, infoIconImage.size.height);

//assigning customized button
infoButton.customView = iButton;
```

Comment: does anyone have an idea why when I assign the iButton to my infoButton which was created in the storyboard, the push action gets disabled? My suspicion goes towards UIControlStateNormal.

Comment: It's not *UIControlStateNormal*, because this just tells the button that the image you pass (infoIconImage) is the image of the button for the *normal* state. So no problem here I think.. I'll let you know if an idea comes to my mind..